# Ajax function not called

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hey guys i got a problem with an ajax function call. I try to reach the page "delete.php", but it never gets called. Here is my script code:

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function deleteSpark(sparkID) {

                    var answer = confirm(sparkID);
                    //Send the user to the correct page when he presses 'yes / oke'
                    if(answer==0){
                        var ajax= $.ajax({ type: "post",
                            data: {sparkid: sparkID },
                            url: 'delete.php'
                        });
                        ajax.done(function(){
                            window.location.href = "/sparks.html";
                        });

                        ajax.fail(function(){
                            window.location.href = "/index.html";
                        })
                    }
                    /* OR*/



                    /* this method after all other code in handler*/
                // window.location.href = "/delete.php?sparkid=" + sparkID;
                // window.location.href = "/sparks.html";
                //Returns false so no events will be executed.
                return false;

            }
```

I call it then with a button: delete 8

And in my php file "delete.php" i do this: $sparkID = $_POST['sparkid'];

but it never gets called, because I try to echo and do some other things that won't work. Can somebody help me?

Comment: `confirm` method returns boolean. do `if(answer==false)` and then execute.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment yet.  Can you inspect element (Firefox/Chrome), then look at the Network tab while the AJAX is running?  This should show the data being sent, which page it is being sent to, etc... and should help you debug.

You might want to also try using an absolute URL initially to make sure it's getting to the right page.

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

I assume, if the return false isn't for prevent the event, that you want the return false when the confirm isn't "yes". So I moved the return false in a `else` statement.

Now as pointed by @Sergey Yarotskiy your `if` statetement is the real problem because you are waiting for a 0; you can combine ( if you need the variable answer somewhere else ) like so : `if(answer = confirm(sparkID)){` or if it's not needed like so : `if(confirm(sparkID)){`.

Hope this will help you.

This should fix it :

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function deleteSpark(sparkID) {
                    //Send the user to the correct page when he presses 'yes / oke'
                    if(answer = confirm(sparkID)){
                        var ajax= $.ajax({ type: "post",
                            data: {sparkid: sparkID },
                            url: 'delete.php'
                        });
                        ajax.done(function(){
                            window.location.href = "/sparks.html";
                        });

                        ajax.fail(function(){
                            window.location.href = "/index.html";
                        })
                    }else{
                     return false;
                    }

            }
```

Comment: Sorry, downvoted because answer is totally incorrect. Returning false just prevent default action. It will not stop AJAX event listeners from listening for response. When response will be received (or error) callback will be called anyway. So problem is that ajax not called at all, but not in the return statement.

Comment: @SergeyYarotskiy return false prevent default yes this is true but fonction don't have "default" event. Since there a confirm I assumed that the OP wanted to have a return false if the confirm wasn't accepted because if it's accepted the page will change. Plus have you notice the chance in the `if` statment ?

Comment: We don't know how deleteSpark function is called. In printed piece of code returning false will prevent default only if whole function used as event callback like $("button").click(deleteSpark); And will not, if it called like $("button").click(function() { deleteSpark(); ); But it still does not related to the nature of existing error.

Comment: Still my answer had the `if` statement corrected. If `$("button").click(function() { deleteSpark(); );` was used then the return false should have inside the click function like so : `$("button").click(function() { deleteSpark(); return false;} );` There's in my opinion nothing wrong about my answer.

Comment: Sorry, code is correct, but very first sense says "It's because Ajax is asynchro." Even if ajax is async, and you code is correct, problem is not "because" ajax is async. And we don't want people just copy correct code. We want them to understand the behavior of their code.

Comment: I will Edit my post then to be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

'confirm' will return true or false instead of 0, so change condition to

```
if (answer) {
    // do staff
}
```

Comment: Just opened his url in browser (just //) and it returned me "file not found" with redirection to file://// ... . Can it be browser or server specific? I'm using firefox on ubuntu. Any way if you want bulletproof code why not to avoid such questions at all?

Comment: This URL won't work if you navigate directly to it, but used in HTML for Images, CSS or JS it will automatically preserve the protocol (HTTP or HTTPS). This is recommended since browsers don't like to cross-load parts (HTML over HTTP including JS over HTTPS or the other way around).